# Get Query Details From A URL Without Parsing It In Java

Tags: java, uri

I am trying to receive name and value (query details) from a URL but I have a restriction that the URL shouldn't be parsed to find out query details from the URL. I tried to find the index of '?' and then add the substring on a list till index of '='-1 from the query which I found using the statement:

```
String query = uri.getQuery() == null || uri.getQuery().trim().isEmpty() ? "" : uri.getQuery();
```

The issue that comes here is I am getting an error which states:

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index

Can anyone point where am I going wrong ?

The URL which I am using is:

```
https://xyzz.com.in/collections/two-tone-wedding-rings?ugg_9ty554_tags=ROSE|WHITE&ugg_yuiolz_price=%3A700%201000%20%7B0%7D%20-%20%7B1%7D
```

(The | symbol is creating issues)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong class for this
I tried doing it with URL class instead

```
String input = "https://xyzz.com.in/collections/two-tone-wedding-rings?ugg_9ty554_tags=ROSE|WHITE&ugg_yuiolz_price=%3A700%201000%20%7B0%7D%20-%20%7B1%7D\n"
URL uri = new URL(input);
System.out.println(uri.getQuery());
```

Output:

```
ugg_9ty554_tags=ROSE|WHITE&ugg_yuiolz_price=%3A700%201000%20%7B0%7D%20-%20%7B1%7D
```